# Enumeration with factorial

Tags: combinatorics

Find all triples ***(a, b, c)*** of positive integers such that $a! +b! =c!$  Justify your answer.

How can I justify it, I seem cannot find a solution.

Comment: A solution is $a = b = 1, c = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

$1!+1!=2!$ is the only solution because

if either $a\ge c$ or  $b \ge c$ then $a!+b! >c!$

if $a<c$ and $b<c$

then we can use the fact that $n!>2(n-1)!$ for $n>2$

then for $n>2$
$$ a!+b! \le  2(c-1)! < c! $$